# how to create multiple axis for python ezhc

Tags: python, highcharts

I want display multiple Y-axis using python ezhc([Higstock chart](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezhc/0.4.8)). I am adding more than one Y-axis as follows, however for some reason both the axis are shown on right hand side of the chart. Kindly let me know what is the issue here

```
g.xAxis=[{
        "categories": ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        "crosshair": "true"
    }]

g.yAxis=[
    {

        "title": {
            "text": 'hello',

        },
         "opposite": "false"


    },

 {

        "title": {
            "text": 'Temperature',

        },
        "opposite": "true"

 }
```

]

```
g.series=[
{
    "data":df["volt"],
    "yAxis": 1,
    "type":"column"

},
 {
    "data":df["temp"],
    "yAxis": 2,
     "type":"line"
}
```

]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, buy you have `"yAxis": 1,` and `"yAxis": 2,`. While you have just two yAxis items (arrays starts at 0-index).

Comment: @PawełFus that is not the problem, problem is all axis are drawn at right side

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see **ANY** series connected to the first yAxis (which has `opposite: false` option set). Arrays in JS are indexed from `0`, so you should have: `yAxis: 0` and `yAxis: 1`.